# Cannot get variables to display values in edittext form

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that's main layout consists of a row of buttons on top of a LinearLayout which hold a form made up of edittexts. I've created a Form object to hold all the values to be displayed in the edittexts for each form. Each button is clicked to change the form's data to show the values held in each Form object. I have the Form objects kept in a List so that I can access each one when the corresponding button is pressed.

EDIT: I've realized I didn't quite explain myself properly. When I click one of the buttons, I want the EditText values to change to a different set of values which correspond to that button.  But when I click these buttons, the previously entered values do not show up. I referred to the column of EditTexts a form, but it's just a column of EditTexts.

When I click Next Drink, it dynamically creates a button as well as a Form object, and clears the EditTexts so that it looks like a new form has been created for the new button. I should then be able to add strings to the EditTexts, and the strings should be stored in the Form object so that if I click that button again, the Form object will fill the EditTexts with the strings stored in that object.

So, if I click button 3 after having clicked button 2, it should set the text of each EditText to the values contained in the the third Form object, which contains strings for Name, Volume, Percentage, Price, and Quantity.

My problem is the values do not show up in the EditTexts after clicking a button. So if I click Button 3, the values from Form 3 don't show up. I've been at this for a long time and cannot figure out why, so I'd really appreciate any help. Here is the activity:

```
package com.example.DrinkApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */




//view variables
final Button newDrink[] = new Button[100];
LinearLayout drinkSelectionContainer;
EditText name;
EditText vol;
EditText perc;
EditText pri;
AutoCompleteTextView quant;

//counters
int numOfDrinks = 0;
int selectedForm = 0;


//array to hold all Form objects.
List<Form> formList = new ArrayList<Form>();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //get views
    drinkSelectionContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drinkSelectContainer);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    vol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etVol);
    perc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPerc);
    pri = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
    quant = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
    Button saveDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveForm);

    Button nextDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNextDrink);
    Button crunkOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalc);

    ///////////////////////// next drink method
    addNewDrinkButton();



    name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            formAdd();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

//                mNames.add(selectedForm, name.getText().toString());
//                newDrink[selectedForm].setText(name.getText().toString());

        }
    });
    nextDrink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addNewDrinkButton();
        }

    });

}






//listener for drink select buttons. when button is clicked, it finds out which one it was,
//and then displays the correct values.
public View.OnClickListener drinkSelectListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        selectedForm = v.getId();
        Form form = formList.get(selectedForm);
        Button v1 = (Button) findViewById(selectedForm);
        v1.setText(" " + selectedForm);
        // Do something depending on the value of the tag
        Log.v("My Logs:", "Select Drink " + selectedForm + " button pressed.");
        Log.v("My Logs:", "Drink " + selectedForm + " name: " + form.getName());


        formDisplay(form);


    }
};


private void addNewDrinkButton() {
    formClear();
    formAdd();
    numOfDrinks++;

    selectedForm = numOfDrinks;
    Log.v("My Logs:", "Next Drink button pressed.");


    newDrink[numOfDrinks] = new Button(getBaseContext());
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setOnClickListener(drinkSelectListener);
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setId(numOfDrinks);


    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setText("" + selectedForm);
    newDrink[numOfDrinks].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // name.setText("Drink " + (numOfDrinks+1));

    drinkSelectionContainer.addView(newDrink[numOfDrinks]);



    //TODO: save form values, clear edit texts, and create new variables for edittexts.    
}


void formAdd(){

    Form tempForm = new Form();

    tempForm.setId(selectedForm);
    tempForm.setName(name.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setVolume(vol.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setPercentage(perc.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setPrice(pri.getText().toString());
    tempForm.setQuantity(quant.getText().toString());

    formList.add(selectedForm, tempForm);

}

void formDisplay(Form form){

    name.setText(form.getName());
    vol.setText(form.getVolume());
    perc.setText(form.getPercentage());
    pri.setText(form.getPrice());
    quant.setText(form.getQuantity());


}


void formClear(){

    name.setText("");
    vol.setText("");
    perc.setText("");
    pri.setText("");
    quant.setText("");


    }
}
```

![Here's the main layout. So if I click button 4, I want to have the EditTexts display the values
I'd entered the last time I'd clicked on it. It's really very simple, I'm having trouble explaining myself today.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qiBs.png)

Comment: Please clarify our question and provide some visuals if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided doesn't seem to coincide with your question. You want to put values into an EditText view and then hit a button that takes the values from that EditText view and places it inside of a "form"? If so, then inside of onCreate() and after you have setContentView() try:

```
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id."edit_text_id");  // where "edit_text_id" is your your EditText view id set in your xml
String text = name.getText().toSting();

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id."forms_text_field"); // where "forms_text_field" is your TextView id set in your form's xml
textView.setText(text);
```

Repeat this for each of your EditText views (setting a corresponding TextView in your form to the desired EditText field value). This should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the values have to be editable. That's why I'm not using TextViews to display them. When I click one of the buttons, I want to display a previous set of entered EditText values that corresponds to that button so that they can be changed in necessary.

Comment: Wait, what? When you click the button what exactly do you want to be displayed, can you update your post to include an example of what you want to achieve because as far as a I understand it this is what you want to do. How do you want to display it if you don't have any sort of view?